# Google OIDC error. "Error 400: invalid_scope. Requests for only id token must contain a subset of [openid, email, profile] scopes."

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, openid-connect, google-authentication

We have a react app which is authenticated with Google OIDC. It was working fine and suddenly users got below error out of nowhere.

```
Error 400: invalid_scope. Requests for only id token must contain a subset of [openid, email, profile] scopes
```

We need to access user data so our scope for auth provider is,

`export const AUTH_OIDC_SCOPE ='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'`

Auth code:

```
  const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider(AUTH_PROVIDER)
  provider.addScope(AUTH_OIDC_SCOPE)

  const authenticateWithGcp = () => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .catch((error) => {
        return error
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        user.getIdToken(true).then((token) => {
          ....
        })
      } else {
        authenticateWithGcp()
      }
    })
  }, [])
```

Any idea how to fix the error, while keeping admin.directory.user in scope?

[image]

Comment: try to add openid to the scope list like export const AUTH_OIDC_SCOPE ='openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user' ?

Comment: Tried AUTH_OIDC_SCOPE ='openid googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user' . not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the error message, it says "Requests for only ID token" and that is the problem here.

when you ask for only the ID-token, then you need to ask for the user details like openid, email or profile..... Otherwise the id-token would be empty.

And just asking for the ID-token means that you don't want any access token. So that means the AUTH_OIDC_SCOPE should be

```
AUTH_OIDC_SCOPE ='openid email profile'
```

If that is want you meant to do.

Comment: yes this works. I had use `user` scope as a seperate string to pass to user fetching scenario.

Comment: Great! Glad it worked!